# Unity3D Getting position of OVRCameraRig

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I want to attach an object to the OVRCameraRig and then use its position, which is offset from the rig.

However, my object is always static, irrespective of where the headset is.

This only happens with the OVRCameraRig. If I use a normal MainCamera I get the right data. But I'm not getting other aspects, like floor level, of the OVRCameraRig!

Is there some way to get the actual position of the OVRCameraRig?

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?  I have a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63831411/unity3d-placing-a-cube-in-front-vr-player-and-move-with-player-position-and-rota Do you think you will be able to answer this?

Comment: The answer to this question was accepted by me. So, yes, I was able to achieve it. See below.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work for me. I am new to Unity maybe I am missing something there. Appreciate if you could share the code snippet that worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik the `OVRCameraRig` itself doesn't move.

What you probably want to get is the position of the [`centerEyeAnchor`](https://developer.oculus.com/reference/unity/1.29/class_o_v_r_camera_rig/#a2716fdeda387531693c0c1f83b7a1b57) instead

```c#
// somehow get the reference e.g. using GetComponent
OVRCameraRig overCameraRig;

var position = overCameraRig.centerEyeAnchor.position;
```

Regardless of the value of `usePerEyeCameras` the `centerEyeAnchor`'s position is always updated.

Comment: Thank you @derHugo. That worked and made the difference! Very confusing and unintuitive as I had tried the OVRCameraRig object and the TrackingSpace object and both returned a vector3.zero so I didn't expect the anchor's to return anything either!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to get the `OVRCameraRig` position using the `centerEyeAnchor` attribute.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class OVRCameraPosTest : MonoBehaviour {
    
    [SerializeField] private OVRCameraRig overCameraRig;
    
    void Start() {
        Vector3 cameraPos = GetCameraPos();
        Debug.Log("Camera Position: " + cameraPos);
    }

    Vector3 GetCameraPos() {
        // Remove this line if you are refering the OVRCameraRig component 
        // through the inspector to the script.
        overCameraRig = GameObject.Find("OVRCameraRig").GetComponent<OVRCameraRig>();
        return overCameraRig.centerEyeAnchor.position;
    }
}
```